# Magento Product Import Issue

Tags: magento-1.9

Im trying to run an import into magento and getting the following error.

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list', query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity` (`sku`, `entity_type_id`, `attribute_set_id`, `type_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `0`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Any advice / suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By default catalog_product_entity does not contain a column with the name 0.

[image]

```
INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity (sku, entity_type_id, attribute_set_id, type_id, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
```

Or if you do have an extra column in your catalog_product_entity you will need to confirm the name and then make sure it matches what is in your query.